# Django model is present, says not defined when running code

Tags: python, django

i have the following model:

```
class Basestationreport(models.Model):
    ...
    gpstimeanddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='GPSTimeAndDate')  # Field name made lowercase.
    ...
```

And code:

```
from .models import Basestationreport

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def getbasestationsbetween(request):
    fromdate = request.POST.get('from')
    todate = request.POST.get('to')
    result = Basestationreport.objects.filter(gpstimeanddate > datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(request.POST), content_type="application/json")
```

The error i get is:

> NameError: name 'gpstimeanddate' is not defined.

My other functions which use other fields from this table work fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because its looking for a local variable called `gpstimeanddate` which you obviously haven't defined, nor are trying to use.

Since you're trying to use it as a field to filter results on you need to use it as a keyword in fiter, as well as use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gt)

```
.filter(gpstimeanddate__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`_gt` should be used instead of `>`. You can read more from this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

```
result = Basestationreport.objects.filter(gpstimeanddate__gt = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
result = Basestationreport.objects.filter(gpstimeanddate > datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Should be

```
result = Basestationreport.objects.filter(gpstimeanddate__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Django queries like filter only accept keyword arguments, not boolean expressions. Check out [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#gt), and generally the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__gt` instead of `>` :

```
result = Basestationreport.objects.filter(gpstimeanddate__gt = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

All of the docs links given above are broken,
here's an updated link : [__gt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt)